# MySQL Database Design Help?

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin

I am going through my database and what I want to do is re-design it because I feel like it's very messy and that I am doing it wrong. This is just for practice; I've never had anyone teach me so I would love to learn new ways and how to approach this.

What I have is a users table with the following fields:

id, admin, active, username, password, business_name, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, hours, hours2, credit_cards, logo_ext, package, theme, header_image, facebook_link, twitter_link, analytics, analytics_id, website_url, banner_image, member_forgot, home_page, about_page, contact_page

Wow, pretty messy right?  Here are a few things I see:

admin and active is just a bunch of 0's and 1's so can I do something like this? Since there will be 99% active and only a couple that will be inactive.

**admin**  - id, user_id

**inactive** - id, user_id

**social** - id, user_id, facebook_link, twitter_link

**member_forgot** - id, user_id, forgot_code

I'm not too sure about the rest.   Just to explain a few of the fields:

- Hours = Monday through Friday hours
- Hours2 = Saturday hours
- Credit_Cards = 1110 format (visa, mastercard, discover, amex)
- logo_ext = jpg, png - stores it when you upload logo
- package = 1, 2, or 3. Different level. Each level has its own template.
- theme = what stylesheet to use
- header_image = which image to use on the header for that account.
- analytics_id = I use piwik, so piwik stores a unique id that I need to store
- banner_image = 1-30 of different images there are to choose from
- pages = stores the text in the database, which they can change via wysiwyg editor.

I really want to practice splitting it up in different tables even if it is not a huge database, or is that a bad idea? So if I delete a user from the users table, it will delete all of the other records in the other tables associated with that user_id?

Any suggestions / help is appreciated.  I love to learn new things and am very interested in making this database more efficient and flexible.

Thanks so much.

Comment: This is a design to capture the model of *what*?

Answer (score 2):

> admin and active is just a bunch of 0's and 1's so can I do something
>   like this? Since there will be 99% active and only a couple that will
>   be inactive.
>
> admin - id, user_id
>   inactive - id, user_id
>   social - id, user_id
>   facebook_link, twitter_link
>   member_forgot - id, user_id, forgot_code

Actually no, I wouldn't do this and keep it in the same table. The flag should be enough to distinguish between these two. The only difference in your queries is a `active = true`. Personally, I wouldn't consider this a bad design choice (altough your idea is not wrong, I would not use it in this case with - I'm guessing - a small set of data). Since only on set of data belongs to a single user, `JOIN`s would make not that much sense.

> I really want to practice splitting it up in different tables even if
>   it is not a huge database, or is that a bad idea? So if I delete a
>   user from the users table, it will delete all of the other records in
>   the other tables associated with that user_id?

Again, I wouldn't do that personally(!). I don't see a benefit of seperating user centric data from the user. If you fear losing the data on deletion, introduce a `deleted` flag. This way, you will never lose data and your application just respects the `deleted` flag in your queries (this would also apply if you split the data accross tables).

> Credit_Cards = 1110 format (visa, mastercard, discover, amex)

Storing credit cards is always very sensitive, according to PCI (as far as i remember) you are not allowed to store the CVV code (hope someone can correct me on that). But since this seems to be a fictional application, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your response.  Regarding the credit cards, that is just to see which credit cards that user (shop) accepts in their store.